# Versión de python 3

Tags: elementary-website

***Hola ¿Qué versión de python trae Hera?
¿Cómo puedo hacer que la ultima versión (en el caso de instalarle la ultima) sea
la predeterminada?***

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config python` o `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` depende en que usas más. En Hera, la predeterminada es la misma alrededor de Linux: Python 3.6.

Comment: Gracias lo checare

Answer (score 0):

`sudo update-alternatives --config python` o `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` depende en que usas más. En Hera, la predeterminada es la misma alrededor de Linux: Python 3.6.

(Subiendo como una respuesta oficial para que puedes marcar este pregunta como respondida)